# VB How to generically implement exception logging if I have already got many try-catch block

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, logging

I am writing ASP.Net Web-form in VB.

I have a system which have already handled exceptions by try-catch blocks everywhere.
How do I quickly and generically implement exception logging like overriding something instead of inserting logging functions in every single catch block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an AOP framework like [Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) you can hook on exceptions thrown and log a message, but that will only work if you haven't already handled them in your code.

Your best bet would be to refactor your exception handling code. Apart from the global catch-all exception handling, you should only have try-catch blocks in places where you can actually handle the exception. And in those cases you probably want to add a specific message in the log telling *why* and how this exception was handled.

Comment: Thanks Meta-Knight~ Is there any way to apply the [OnException] attribute globally? I hope there is some way doesn't required to add this attribute to every top of methods.

Comment: @Mr.Redpill: There is a way to intercept any exception without having to add attributes. But I don't remember how exactly; you could ask on Postsharp forums for help.

Comment: Thanks Meta-Knight, you are helpful.

Comment: Oh, I found this post in post sharp, as I have already added catch block , it sounds postsharp can't intercept it.
http://www.sharpcrafters.com/forum/Topic7408-18-1.aspx#bm7622
"Sorry, I did not see your first post.
There's no way to intercept handled exceptions (i.e. wrap catch blocks) with PostSharp. You can only intercept unhandled exceptions.

-gael"

Comment: OK, my bad, I thought we traced handled exceptions with PostSharp in our app but I suppose it was just unhandled exceptions then. I'll edit my answer accordingly.